# Is there a way to subtract an element with next element in a python list?

Tags: python

Iam new to programming and started learning python.
Iam having a list if numbers
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
Logic should be 1-2-3-4-5 to get the result as -13.
Someone help me with the python code for this problem.

Comment: Start by looking up what a for loop is and how to use it

Comment: `functools.reduce(operator.sub, a)` (inspired by chepner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use a for loop and a temporary variable, subtracting the number each time.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5] #initiate array
temp = a[0] #set the value to the first number
for i in a[1:]:
    temp -= i #update value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother

Comment: You should mark this as the answer if this helped! (There is a checkmark near the arrows)